# Is there an optical filter which exclusively passes right or left circularly polarized light?

Tags: optics

Is there a circular analog to the linear polarizer filter, which can be configured to pass only right (left) and block left (right) circularly polarized light?

Comment: What would this filter do with linearly-polarized light? Reject it, or pass 50% intensity? What about light that's just about circularly polarized, but has slight (say, 1%) imperfections in the ellipticity? That is, are you looking for a linear filter, or something that will only pass perfectly polarized light. The latter is essentially impossible; the former is most commonly realized in [3D cinema lenses](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70384/are-these-sunglass-lenses-linearly-polarized-or-what).

Comment: I believe I had a anti-glare screen for a monitor that worked on that principle once. It accepted the same handedness both ways, but of course reflected light swaps handedness. Can't find a reference.

Comment: A linear polarizer sandwiched between two quarter wave plates (aligned correctly).

Comment: Thanks @ThePhoton, that's what I'm looking for. It seems to be called a homogenous circular polarizer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Homogeneous_circular_polarizer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just described the 3D glasses handed out in movie theatres.

So, the answer is "yes."  :-) .   To be more helpful, here's a quote from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarized_3D_system)

> As shown in the figure, the analyzing filters are constructed of a
>   quarter-wave plate (QWP) and a linearly polarized filter (LPF). The
>   QWP always transforms circularly polarized light into linearly
>   polarized light. However, the angle of polarization of the linearly
>   polarized light produced by a QWP depends on the handedness of the
>   circularly polarized light entering the QWP. In the illustration, the
>   left-handed circularly polarized light entering the analyzing filter
>   is transformed by the QWP into linearly polarized light which has its
>   direction of polarization along the transmission axis of the LPF.
>   Therefore, in this case the light passes through the LPF. In contrast,
>   right-handed circularly polarized light would have been transformed
>   into linearly polarized light that had its direction of polarization
>   along the absorbing axis of the LPF, which is at right angles to the
>   transmission axis, and it would have therefore been blocked.