# Is there a way to physically resolve elliptically polarized light into circularly polarized components?

Tags: optics, polarization

I was reading about a phenomenon called [circular dichroism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dichroism), in which LCP(left circularly polarized) and RCP(right circularly polarized) light are absorbed to different extents. Hence, when linearly polarized light(LCP+RCP with some phase between them) is passed though such a material, the output beam is elliptically polarized.

Can this elliptically polarized beam be "split up" physically, into constituent left and right circularly polarized beams. What I am picturing is a plate the lets only the LCP pass through or vice-versa.

Comment: For your interest: www.itos.de/en/itos-polarizers/circular-polarizers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to pass the beam through a quarter-wave plate, then through a traditional beam splitter that separates  horizontal from vertical polarization, then through a quarter-wave plate again.

Comment: Pretty much. For an everyday instance (minus the second QWP), take a pair of modern 3D cinema glasses. (More details on this site [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70384).)