# Can non-monochromatic light be elliptically or circularly polarised?

Tags: optics

We all know that monochromatic light is always polarised.  Non-monochromatic light can obviously also be linearly polarised.  However, can non-monochromatic light be elliptically or circularly polarised?

Comment: all satellite communications and some radar signals are circularly polarized, these are always modulated and *not* monochromatic.

Comment: There is no such thing as monochromatic light and so the comment that is it always polarised doesn't matter. 

Also linearly polarised light can be expressed as a superposition of circularly polarised light and visa versa so fundamentally they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some subtleties around the edges of this question, but the short answer is **yes**.

Non-monochromatic light is made up of some combination (which might be coherent or incoherent) of light of a range of different frequencies. If each component of that combination is circularly polarized, then we say that the combination is circularly polarized.

- If the combination is coherent, then it is a linear superposition that forms some form of pulse, in which case the field shape rotates with time; see e.g. [this paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-03167-2) for a recent example.
- If the combination is incoherent, then it becomes quite hard to say anything about the detailed time dependence of the pulse, which will generally be a mess, but it will tend to rotate in the specified direction.

In either case, to actually make a non-monochromatic circular polarization, you need a [quarter-wave plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate) as usual -- except that the plate will need to add exactly a quarter-wavelength of optical path to each wavelength, which can't be achieved with a plate of constant birefringence $\Delta n$. Instead, what's needed is an [achromatic waveplate](https://www.google.com/search?q=achromatic+waveplate) whose birefringence $\Delta n$ changes with wavelength in precisely the right way; this is mostly doable over limited frequency ranges, but it gets more and more challenging (and expensive) as the bandwidth of interest increases.

Comment: What about elliptical polarisation?

Comment: @delickcrow123 The same, but more complicated, and there's generally less point to using such fields. (One such complication: what if you have two components of the same ellipticity, but with different orientations of the polarization ellipse?) [Here](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nphoton.2014.108) is one example with an elliptically-polarized non-monochromatic broadband pulse (and see [here](http://hdl.handle.net/10044/1/41942) for a more accessible review), so they can definitely be useful, but I generally see little point in invoking them unless you really need them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The two images in a 3D cinema are left- and right-handed circularly polarized.

If you have a pair of such 3D-glasses, it is fun to look in a mirror, and close your right eye or your left eye.

Comment: [More on cinema 3D glasses](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70384/are-these-sunglass-lenses-linearly-polarized-or-what).