# What components would produce this polarization/waveplate demo?

Tags: optics, polarization

An optics demonstration that I saw many years ago involved two identical-looking transparent plastic "slides", about the size of microscope slides. Call them slides A and B. *Individually*, they were transparent to ordinary ambient light passing through them in either direction. However, when stacked together, the *stack* was transparent only when viewed from one side, and was opaque when viewed from the opposite side:

```
        |   |   |  
        | A | B |  
        |   |   |  
     -------------> 1  
        |   |   |   
        |   |   | 
   0 <------------- 
        |   |   |
```

I recall that this had to do with polarization, and at least one of the slides was a waveplate (quarter?, half?), but I can't figure out exactly what must have been used to produce this effect. Help, please?

Comment: By 'transparent', do you mean *fully* transparent, or with some absorbance (say, around the level of common sunglasses)? How does it compare, say, to the pictures [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70384/are-these-sunglass-lenses-linearly-polarized-or-what)?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - As, I recall, they were individually fully transparent, practically indistingushable from ordinary microscope slides (except perhaps a bit thicker).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The configuration makes no sense to me.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - Thanks very much for that link. The effect is so similar to what is described there, I think I must have simply misremembered the demo. (Sorry to have cluttered the site with this, my first question. Can it be simply deleted?)

Comment: You can delete it if you really feel you need to, but if that's what you meant then the best course of action is to close it as a duplicate - you should see a prompt on the question now, and clicking "that solved my problem" will close it automatically.